# What is the difference between nun, jetzt and gerade?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Nun, jetzt and gerade can all be translated as 'now'. When should I use these and what are their meanings? Are there any differences between them or are they interchangeable?

Comment: No, these terms aren't arbitrarily interchangable.

Comment: "Nur" and "gerade" almost never translate as "now". These three words all have a totally different meaning.